# How can I pass a URL Parameter after Update of a form in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, url, parameters

I am trying to figure out how to pass a url parameter with the parent foreign key of a record on submitting an update of a record.  I'd like to see the the parent record after successfully updating the child record.  I can't seem to figure it out.  I am using Rails 4.

```
Project:
has_many: events

Event:
belongs_to: project
```

I've defined the as

```
event.project_id as :pid
```

This is my form_tag code:

```
<%= form_tag verify_dates_events_path, method: :put do  %>
```

Comment: How about in your `update` action, when you perform the redirection after updating the model, you specify a parameter. Like: `redirect_to root_path(post_id: @post.id)`

Comment: Oh, man.  Thank you.  It was so simple and obvious it was hard to Google-find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should redirect to the project page after updating the event. Assuming you have defined the following resources:

```
resources :projects
resources :events
```

In your `EventsController` `update` action, you can do something like:

```
def update
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  if @event.update_attributes(params[:event])
    redirect_to project_path(@event.project)
  else 
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I do have the resources set, but I appreciate the walk-through on the redirect.